# 400- BAD Request (ajax) for longer URLs

Tags: ajax, wcf

I created a html page which accepts user input and on clicking ‘submit’, sends an ajax request(GET) to a WCF web service running on my machine. 
A user input can vary from 100 characters to 1000 characters. I am getting perfect results till the time user enters 500 characters or less (url length <560). However, as soon as the input length is more than 500 characters (url length = 560), I get an error – 400 – BAD REQUEST.

I have changed the web config file for my web service as below:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name ="" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="02:00:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

Etc…

but I am still getting the same error for inputs > 500

Ajax Request from html page:

```
 $.ajax({ 
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 600000,
            crossDomain: true,
            url: 'http://localhost:53518/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/' + inputData, 
            success: function (response) {
                    var tableData = response.GetInventoryDataResult;
                    populateTable(tableData); 
                }
                else
                {                                    
                    $('#demotable').show();
                    alert("No data found for the entered SerialIDs.");

                }
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, statusText, errorThrown) { 
                console.log("readyState:" + jqXhr.readyState + "responseText:" +  jqXhr.responseText + "StatusCode:" + jqXhr.status + "statusText:" + jqXhr.statusText);
            }

        });
```

Kindly suggest. 
Do I need to make changes to web.config file of my wcf service which receives the GET request? 
Please Note: The code works perfectly fine for smaller urls

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION FOUND**

The maximum number characters allowed in a parameter (value between two slashes inside a URL) is default 260. 
This can be read here: [Http.sys registry changes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/820129/http-sys-registry-settings-for-windows)
This can be changed by making registry changes to the machine where web server is running. Go to regedit and change the value of UrlSegmentMaxLength to a desired value. Maximum decimal value can be - 32,766 chars. 
 **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters**

Do not forget to restart your system once registry changes are made.
If you do not find UrlSegmentMaxLength under the Parameters then create a new DWORD type with value as UrlSegmentMaxLength  and data as any integer that you want 0-32,766 chars